# Android: listFiles() doesn't find file created with FileWriter

Tags: android, filewriter

I create a txt-File with FileWriter:

```
try
    {
        fw = new FileWriter( filePath );
        fw.write("Name: " + title);

        fw.write("Publisher: " + publisher + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fw.write("Author: " + author + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fw.write("Book Version: " + version + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fw.write("URL: " + url + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fw.write("ThumbMD5: " + thumbMD5 + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fw.write("FileMD5: " + fileMD5 + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fw.write("Book Area Code: " + areaCode + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fw.write("Type: " + type + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) {
        Log.e(TAG, "saveTxt: Couldn't create File: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
    finally {
        if ( fw != null )
            try { fw.close(); } catch ( IOException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

That file gets created correctly, with correct content. I can open the file when I connect my Smartphone with a windows PC.

But when I try

```
File dirTxt = new File(Helper.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Helper.getFileCache());
File[] txts = dirTxt.listFiles();
for (File txt : txts) {
        Log.e(TAG, txt.getName());
}
```

all files in that directory are found, but my new txt file.
What's up with that? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: instead of looking for the new File and coping it, I just used

```
File f = new File(pathToNewFile);
```

Then i copied f.